# Is there an Azure platform service that can convert text from pdf files and save those unstructured data in database?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-analysis-services

Our organization is migrating our routine work onto Azure Cloud platform. One of my works is using Python to read many pdf files and convert all the text/unstructured data into tables, e.g.
first column shows the file name and second column saves all the text data etc.

Just wondering is there a service in Azure platform that can achieve this automatically? I am new user to Azure, so not quite familiar with this. Thanks heaps if any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at [Azure AI Document Intelligence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/overview?tabs=v3-0) (previously called Azure Form Recognizer). You can train it to recognize tables and extract data from PDF files.

Comment: thanks for answering, I knew it is pretty good for forms/images, is that also handy to extract all the text from pdf files? thanks